# Software with automatic kerning?

Tags: typesetting, kerning

I'm working on a logotype in Sketch and has set some text in Futura. Unfortunately the kerning looks quite bad and I'm not skilled enough to correct it manually using the character spacing property in Sketch.

Indesign has an automatic/algorithmic kerning setting called 'Optical kerning' which usually produces great results but I don't have access to any Adobe software at the moment.

**Is there any other software that has high quality automatic kerning?**

Comment: What kind of output are you looking for? (Vector, web images, high quality rasters for reproduction, ...) Can you add an image or two showing some of this bad kerning?